# Are Arzelà–Ascoli theorems results of similar theorems on normed spaces, metric spaces or other spaces?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Generalizations), two generalizations of the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem are

> 1. Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Then a subset $F$ of $C(X)$,
>      the set of real-valued continuous functions on X, is relatively
>      compact in the topology induced by the uniform norm if and only if
>      it is equicontinuous and pointwise bounded.
> 2. Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $Y$ a metric space. Then a
>      subset $F$ of $C(X,Y)$ is compact in the compact-open topology if and
>      only if it is equicontinuous, pointwise relatively compact and
>      closed.

$C(X)$ is a normed space with the uniform norm, and also a metric space under the metric induced by the uniform norm. I was wondering if the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem generalizations are direct results of applying  to $C(X)$ some similar theorem(s) on normed spaces, metric spaces or other spaces (which $C(X)$ belongs to) ?

For example, are the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem generalizations results of the following theorem:

> A subset in a metric space is compact iff it is complete and totally
>   bounded?

Or the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem generalizations are not direct results of any similar theorems on normed spaces, metric spaces or other spaces (which $C(X)$ belongs to) ?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: In books that I've read this generalizations was proved by checking completeness and total boundness.

Comment: @Norbert: Thanks! (1) May I have some references? (2) I guess you are talking about the second generalization. For the first generalization, it is not compactness but relative compactness.

Comment: This is book in Russiаn Элементы теории функций и функциональный анализ. А. Н. Колмогоров, С. В. Фомин

Comment: The idea of the proofs of generalized theorems is the same as in thorem for $C([a,b])$.

Comment: @Norbert: Thanks! I found the English version "Elements of Function Theory and Functional Analysis by Kolmogorov and Fomin". Which chapter and volume?

Comment: Chapter 2 in the end of paragraph 7.

Comment: @Norbert: Thanks! What I found is Chapter 2 Section 17 "Arzela's theorem and its application", where it addresses the specialized version of Arzela's theorem for $C[a,b]$ where $a < b \in \mathbb{R}$. It seems not talk about the generalized versions, but I learned from you that "the idea is the same".

Comment: Does English version of the book ended with this theorem or there is something else after it. As I remember a generalized version was after it.

Comment: @Norbert: I have tried but didn't see the generalized versions. Section 17 is the specialized version followed by its application. Here is [the book link at Google](http://books.google.com/books?id=OyWeDwfQmeQC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). Are you able to read it?

Comment: Yes, I am. See page 61